# How to call a module's method within the same module?

Tags: node.js, express

I created a route :

```
var connexion = require('./dbMysql');

exports.getPrefixNomTables = function () {
    return "george_";
};

exports.getRegionIdFromLib = function (regionLib, cb) {
    var ret = 0;
    connexion.query("select region_id from george_region where region_libelle = ? limit 1", [regionLib], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (rows.length > 0)
            ret = rows[0].region_id;
        cb(ret);
    });
};
```

In the `getRegionIdFromLib` function I want to call the `getPrefixNomTables` method instead of hardcoding `george_region`. How to do that ?

Comment: just call `exports. getPrefixNomTables()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `exports.getPrefixNomTables()` inside `getRegionIdFromLib`:

```
exports.getRegionIdFromLib = function (regionLib, cb) {

  var region = exports.getPrefixNomTables()

  // ...

};
```